# Foundation 5 tabs scroll to content for only links using deep linking

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation, deep-linking, zurb-foundation-5

I am using Foundation 5.5.2 and have tabs on a page that allow deep linking. On the homepage of my site I have links with the deep linking hash linking to a specific tab on another page of my site, for these I would like the scroll to content to be enabled. When I have the following code, those links work as desired, with the page opening the correct tab and scrolling to it's content.

```
<ul class="tabs main-tabs" data-tab data-options="deep_linking: true; scroll_to_content: true">
```

However, when I click the link to that same page from the main navigation (the link to that page does not contain any deep-linking hashes), the page still scrolls to the content of the active tab, which it not desired. Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: It would help if you created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) replicating the issue.